# ¿Como acceder a sqlserver desde aplicacion uwp en tablet surface 6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows10, uwp

Tengo una aplicación simple en UWP que accede a una base de datos y extrae un registro. Al ejecutarla en el pc de desarrollo accede muy bien y trae el registro de la base de datos local, de igual manera cuando intento acceder a la BD de la Tablet se conecta, pero a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación en la Tablet, se conecta muy bien a la BD de la pc de desarrollo, pero de ninguna manera se conecta a la base de datos local.

He habilitado el **tcp/ip** y la **conexion remota** del sqlserver

Aqui esta mi codigo

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();           
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connStr = @"data source = DESKTOP-ISFEBNU\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog = Ejemplo; user id = sa; password=Ab123456789;Connect Timeout = 60;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
            SqlConnection conectarbd = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            conectarbd.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from exa", conectarbd);
            SqlDataReader dsCategoria1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dsCategoria1.Read())
            {
                tbAlgo.Text = dsCategoria1[0].ToString().Trim();
            }
            conectarbd.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(ex.ToString());
            dialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
            dialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;
            var cmd = await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

También probé reinstalando el sqlserver
Cabe destacar que tengo una aplicación hecha en visual fox pro y funciona correctamente

[image: Este es el mensage de error]

Comment: Bienvenido Ramón, te sugiero que edites o elimines tu pregunta en base a [ask]... Más allá de tu testimonio, tu pregunta no aporta nada como para que los interesados puedan ayudarte... Y se va ver reflejado en puntuaciones negativas y reportes... Decir que tienes un problema X no nos ayuda a resolverlo, mostrar algo del código o los errores que tengas nos podría acercar más a una solución...

Comment: Asi esta mejor?